# Use of mhchem and chemformula inside a glossary entry

Tags: glossaries, mhchem, chemformula

The following MWE where a glossary entry with a chemical formula defined with `mhchem` renders as expected with 0 errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{DMSO}{DMSO}{dimethyl sulfoxide \ce{(CH3)2SO}}

\begin{document}

\glsunsetall

Solvent: \gls{DMSO}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, when I change `\ce` to `\ch` in `\newacronym` (e.g. switch to `chemformula`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{DMSO}{DMSO}{dimethyl sulfoxide \ch{(CH3)2SO}}

\begin{document}

\glsunsetall

Solvent: \gls{DMSO}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I receive the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \@glo@first ->dimethyl sulfoxide \ch{(CH3)2SO}\glsspace(DMSO)l.12 ...O}{DMSO}{dimethyl sulfoxide \ch{(CH3)2SO}}
```

The problem persists with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` (the latter has different set of packages, obviously, but gives the same error). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have `chemmacros` installed but I suspect it's an expansion problem. Either put `\protect` before `\ch` or [switch off expansion](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:expansion) using `\glsnoexpandfields `.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you very much, `\glsnoexpandfields` in preample did it! I think you can convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: Okay. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any fields contain fragile commands, you need to [switch off the default expansion](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:expansion) using `\glsnoexpandfields` (before defining the terms).

(By default, all fields except `name`, `description` and `symbol` have their values expanded when defining terms to allow for commands that define terms programmatically. The `name`, `description` and `symbol` fields have the expansion switched off by default for historical reasons.)